# Threejs FBX animation won't work after changing object material

Tags: animation, model, three.js, fbx

I've read the FBX Loader example and got the animation to work.
But the FBX Model imports the model with PhongMaterials by default, apparentely.
The problem is that i need it to be the BasicMaterial (the same as 'unlit' in unity). When i try to create a new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial and use the copy() function to pass the data from the Phong material to the desired one, i'll get several errors like this screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lsek.jpg

If i just create a new MeshBasicMaterial, set it's color to be the same as the Phong Material, i won't get any errors, but the animation won't play anymore.

Heres my code:

```
function load_init( object ) {
    mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( object );

    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if ( child.isMesh ) {

            const oldMat = child.material;
            var newMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();

            if(oldMat.length == undefined)//only one material in the mesh
            {
                console.log(newMat.copy(oldMat));//it copies succesfuly

                //child.material = newMat; // gives errors

                child.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {  
                color: oldMat.color,
                } );//materials are changed, but the animation wont play
                    //anymore
            }
            else//multiple materials
            {
                for(var i = 0; i < oldMat.length; i++)
                {
                    console.log(newMat.copy(oldMat[i]));//it copies succesfuly

                    //child.material[i] = newMat; // gives errors

                    child.material[i] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {  
                    color: oldMat[i].color,
                    } );//materials are changed, but the animation wont play
                        //anymore
                }
            }
        }
    } );

    var action = mixer.clipAction( object.animations[ 0 ] );
    action.play();
    scene.add( object );
}
```

Comment: Try to set `skinning: true` for new materials.

Comment: Yup. That was it. But why copying won't work? Saving things like ID and name automatically would be pretty handy.

Comment: What kinds of errors does using the copied new material giving?

Comment: It's in the imgur link on the original post